# Using Leap Motion controller with QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, leap-motion

I was unable to find the answers anywhere else here so here goes:
I have a project I have to do with a Leap Motion controller. [Here is the tutorial.](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/devguide/Sample_Tutorial.html)
Now they explain on this website how to use the Microsoft Visual Studio to compile the Leap programs; however, it is a requirement that I use QT creator for this project in addition to being able to compile for windows. I am getting errors when trying to compile that basically look like this:

error: function 'Leap::Interface::Implementation::~Implementation()' definition is marked dllimport
       LEAP_EXPORT virtual ~Implementation() {}
                           ^

I believe I have everything linked properly to the project and don't understand why I am unable to compile on my windows machine. I think it has to do with the MinGW compiler but am not sure how I would fix that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW isn't fully supported at this time. We have an experimental build, which you can access from here: https://community.leapmotion.com/t/mingw-support-please/270 -- but this doesn't come with any promise of future support.

Another option is to use the WebSocket server, which provides the same tracking data as a JSON string.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll definitely take a look at it. If worse comes to worst, I'll just end up using the version I got working in Visual Studio with the other pieces created in QT. I really wish I just didn't have to use QT haha.